# Where do the oscillations on the output voltage of my buck converter come from?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, stability, oscillation

I am currently building a buck converter. Its main parameters are the following:

- 24V input
- 5V/3A output
- Able to sustain large load transient currents caused by the switching of power LEDs (~2A)

I selected a synchronous buck converter from TI which fits my needs in terms of electrical characteristics, package and cost: the [TPS54302](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS54302). The first prototype was designed following the datasheet recommendations and formulas. The routing of the PCB was done imitating the converter's evaluation board.

Here are the schematics and CAD:

[image: schematic diagram and PCB layout]

(4 layer board, layers 2 and 3 are hidden. They respectively contain GND plane and supply plane)

There are additional capacitor footprints on this design to be able to test different component configurations.

When I actually tested the board, I was satisfied with the main characteristics: efficiency, output current and voltage, input and output ripple.

However, I wanted to test the stability of the power supply and this is where I started observing unexpected behaviors. I don't have any network analyzer or signal generator available, preventing me from measuring the phase margin. Instead, google researches suggested I measure output voltage variations while applying a transient load current (~1A transient with a rise/fall time <1µs). Fortunately, I have a MOSFET driving a power LED on my board. I just had to short-circuit the LED to generate a transient current.

The schematics below show my test setup where MCU_GPIO_1 generates a PWM signal, and MCU_GPIO_2 is continuously set to a high level.

[image: schematic diagram and oscilloscope screenshots]

As you can see, there are significant oscillations on the output voltage when the current load is released. In order to understand the origin of these oscillations, I conducted the following tests:

- playing with the value of the feed-forward capacitor C10
- changing the input capacitor configuration (more MLCCs)
- adding a ferrite bead in series with the 24V input (in place of the D2 protection diode)
- changing the output capacitor configuration (multiple MLCCs or 1 big polymer capacitor)

So far, these "blind" tests led me nowhere. I am looking for new leads to understand what's going on here, before starting the second run of prototypes. So, here are my questions:

1. How can I have oscillations only on the current release and not on the current draw?
2. What could be the deficient element here: routing? Input filter? Other?

Thanks for your help :)

PS: this is my first question on StackExchange. Any advice on improving the form of my question is welcome :)

---

EDIT : Andy Aka gave the answers in the comments: it's an issue related to the bad earthing of the probe. This picture sums it up:

[image: Good vs. bad oscilloscope probe technique]

[Image source](http://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-wikis-components-files/00-00-00-02-43/1738.scope_5F00_probes_5F00_gnd_5F00_wire.jpg)

You won't catch me making that careless mistake again!

Comment: Repeat your measurements but this time connect your probe tip to the same point as your earth clip. What do you see?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Andy. I wrapped a little wire around the ground of my probe. Then, I ran the same test.
The oscillations disappeared ! I feel so dumb right now not to have done this earlier...
Anyway, my SMPS works correctly at least :)

Comment: We've all done it.

Comment: For the more detailed info I would also suggest these excellent [Analog](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/understanding-switching-reg-output-artifacts.html) and [TI](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power_management/simple_switcher/w/simple_switcher_wiki/2243.understanding-measuring-and-reducing-output-voltage-ripple) arcticles

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Repeat your measurements but this time connect your probe tip to the same point as your earth clip. What do you see?

If your probe is picking up a signal directly due to the inductive loop it forms then you will also see it when probe tip is connecting directly to where your earth clip is placed.

> Thanks for the suggestion Andy. I wrapped a little wire around the
>   ground of my probe. Then, I ran the same test. The oscillations
>   disappeared ! I feel so dumb right now not to have done this
>   earlier... Anyway, my SMPS works correctly at least